# Error 405 (HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL)

Tags: ajax, youtube-javascript-api

I am facing this issue
**405 (HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL)**

whereas the method is post in my code

```
$.ajax({
            url: myUrl + "?" + "token=" + AccessToken + "&key=" +dev_key,
            jsonp: 'callback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: 'post',
            data: sendXML,
            success: function (result) {
                alert("hjgh");
            }
        });

function callback(json)
    {
      alert("ghj");
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ajax POST method is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462994/ajax-post-method-is-not-working)

Comment: "?" + "token=" could be rewritten as "?token="

Comment: it dose not matter @RobertoAloi

Comment: "?" + "token=" does not make any affect

Comment: I'm aware that concatenation is not related to your question. It was simply a side note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified 'jsonp' as your 'dataType'. That will cause the method to be 'GET', overriding your 'type' settings.