# ajax POST method is not working

Tags: ajax, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to send the data via ajax POST method my code is

```
$.ajax({
            url: myUrl + "?token=" + accessToken + "&key=" +dev_key,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: 'POST',
            data: sendXML,
            success: function () {
            alert("z");
            }
        });
```

But the **type: 'POST'** is not working I am getting the following error on console:

> Status Code:405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Comment: what is the value of the final url

Comment: @Ayesha  you have specified the dataType as jsonp why is that? usually the jsonp requests are GET type, what server side language you are using, can you post the server side code that is handling the ajax request

Comment: But I want POST cz I want to hit other site on different domain

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post data to JsonP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp)

Comment: @Ayesha does the other domain allow hitting via jsonp? have you confirmed that, also what is the final url that is outputted? and as i said jsonp requests are GET type you cannot make a POST to them

Comment: @3nigma I want to hit youtube I donot know is JSONP enabled or not on youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `$.post` ?

Example:

```
$.post(
    myUrl,
    {
        token: accessToken,
        key: dev_key
    },
    function(result){
        alert(z)
    }
)
```

P.S. Isn't `?` missing after myUrl?

Comment: Question mark is included in my url it dose not make affect i checked it

Answer (score 1):

i think you forgot the ? in the `token` key like this

```
mySql + "?token="
```

otherwise, try this:

```
jQuery.post(
    myUrl + "?token=" + accessToken + "&key=" +dev_key,
    sendXML,
    function() {
        alert('z');
    },
    'JSONP'
);
```

Comment: error on console is **Cannot call method 'post' of undefined**

Comment: than replace jQuery  with `$`